# align vertically image using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a this code:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem Ipmsum<img src="" alt="img" /></li>
    <li>Some Text <img src="img.jpg" alt="img" /></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

I would align vertically through CSS all the `img` Because in this way every image is too near to the text of every `li`

How can I do?

Edit:

I mean to align the img in exactly in column

Comment: you can use the margin property

Comment: You're going to need to provide a more detailed description of how you want this to lay out - preferably with a visual.

Comment: I edited the post maybe now it's clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this JS fiddle that shows how to do what I think you are trying to accomplish

http://jsfiddle.net/J9z5D/

Answer (score 0):

According to [w3schools here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp), you can use this:

```
img
{
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

(you can also use `text-bottom` or `middle`)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the question correctly - but if you are looking at vertical aligning the text with image and giving some margin between the text and image, you could do something like this -

`<li><span>some text</span><img src="something.png" style="vertical-align:top;margin-left:10px"/></li>`